# python's idle not launching

Tags: python

As I am only familiar with very basic command line usage I would appreciate your help. I started to learn python last week using the book by Mark Lutz. I could start idle immediately and customized it by loading additional themes as shown in this video, which worked perfectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMjhv9KvKAs

However, today I got the following error messages when I tried to start idle or idle3:

```
me@mycomputer:/$ idle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 3, in <module>
    from idlelib.pyshell import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'idlelib'

me@mycomputer:/$ idle3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I have python 3.7.9 and 2.7.17 installed and I am still able to run both in the command line. (I need python 2 for sagemath.) My ubuntu-version ist 18.04.5.

I look forward to receiving your advice about how to get idle running again.

Regards,
Cellini

Comment: Presumably you installed python 3.7.9 from somewhere other than the standard Ubuntu repository?

Comment: I installed with "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa".....